# Searchview in Android Java is working but returns wrong value position. How can ı get correct value?

Tags: java, android, fragment, adapter, searchview

I have a project about Movies which using The Movie Db Api. I got my searchview to display the correct results whenever I search for a particular movie. But when I click on the item in the searchview it returns a result from the original list.

For example : I am searching second item but it returns first item.

How do I fix this? Or do I need to override a method for a onclick for the searchview?

Thank you. (I will post my code (I will take out the nonrelated code), my custom adapter has the searchview code in it. The other is my fragment that contains my searchview and listview list).

MovieFragment.class related code

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        // inside inflater we are inflating our menu file.
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

        // below line is to get our menu item.
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.actionSearch);

        // getting search view of our item.
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        // below line is to call set on query text listener method.
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                // inside on query text change method we are
                // calling a method to filter our recycler view.
                filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void filter(String text) {
        // creating a new array list to filter our data.
        ArrayList<MovieResult> filteredlist = new ArrayList<MovieResult>();

        // running a for loop to compare elements.
        for (MovieResult item : listOfMovies) {
            // checking if the entered string matched with any item of our recycler view.
            if (item.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                // if the item is matched we are
                // adding it to our filtered list.
                filteredlist.add(item);
            }
        }
        if (filteredlist.isEmpty()) {
            // if no item is added in filtered list we are
            // displaying a toast message as no data found.
        } else {
            // at last we are passing that filtered
            // list to our adapter class.
            mAdapter.filterList(filteredlist);
        }
    }
```

MovieAdapter.class  related code

```
  @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    public void filterList(ArrayList<MovieResult> filterlist) {
        mMovies = filterlist;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this

> Not using search view from android studio layout it's **Edit text** field for search

```
    val filteredItemsValues: ArrayList<Items> = ArrayList()
```

kotlin code

```
layoutBinding.searchEdTxt.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            filter(s.toString())
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        }

    })
```

filter function

```
private fun filter(text: String) {
    val filterers: ArrayList<Items> = ArrayList()
    for (item in filteredItemsValues) {
        if (item.name.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())
                .contains(text.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()))
        ) {
            filterers.add(item)
        }
    }
    if (filterers.isEmpty()) {
        //  Toast.makeText(this, "No Data Found..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else {
        itemListAdapter.filterList(filterers)
    }
}
```

adapter

```
fun filterList(filtered: List<Items?>) {
    items = filtered as List<Items>
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Read carefully and use accordingly this code.